# 61+ key, Midi Controller, light weight, good piano feel

Tags: digital-piano, midi-controller-keyboard

I am a road warrior looking to practice piano. I have no home which I can play, and so I am looking for something to sling over my back, plug into my laptop, put some headphones on, and practice.

Ergo, does this piano exist?

- 61+ Keys - So I can play a decent range of music
- Keys at least moderately feel like a real piano - so my practice is meaningful and transferable.
- Lightweight - Because this will literally be carried on my back every day, while riding a bicycle.
- Midi Controller - Because I do not need speakers (extra weight) if I can just have it played off my laptop. (using linux; I am sure I can figure something out)
- Powered completely off of usb - Because this will reduce weight.
- Below 15 pounds

Comment: What kind of electrical power will you have? Hauling a lot of batteries? solar panel? tire friction generator? portable wind turbine? Are you aiming for a 12 volt DC operation?

Comment: usb, or wall plug at a public library. Ideally, usb only is what I'd like. Like I said; I can produce the sound on my computer.

Answer (score 2):

61 Keys (sorry no +), USB powered Midi Controller:

M-Audio
Keystation 61es - 61-Key Semi-Weighted USB MIDI Controller

($169)

Weight: **11 lbs.**

http://www.m-audio.com/products/en_us/Keystation61es.html

================================================

88 Keys, USB powered MIDI Controller:

M-Adudio

Keystation 88es - 88-Key Semi-Weighted USB MIDI Controller

($199)

Weight: **22 lbs.**

http://www.m-audio.com/products/en_us/Keystation88es.html

================================================

88 Keys, USB powered MIDI Controller:

Alesis Q88
($199)

Weight: **22 lbs.**

http://alesis.com/q88

http://www.zzounds.com/item--ALEQ88

================================================

M-Audio Keystation 88 - New - 88 Key MIDI Controller

($199)

Weight: **16.9 lbs.**

[http://www.amazon.com/M-Audio-Keystation-88-Keyboard-Controller/dp/B00IWTS58A/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1407195061&sr=8-1&keywords=m-audio+keystation+88](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IWTS58A)

Final Note: I put the 61 key M-Audio on top to show the least amount of weight. Some of the 88 key units say "shipping" weight, so you might want to double check. This is the old
Power vs. Keyboard Size thing. You want to optimize for the least amount of power on your laptop battery, with the maximum number of keys that have the feel of real piano action.

Comment: Why is the 61 key MAudio only 11 pounds, while the 88 key MAudio is 21 pounds? 21 pounds is a bit much, although it would be nice to practice on.

Comment: I just double checked the weights, these are the actual weight. Why is something with 61 keys almost 1/2 the weight of something with 88 keys is beyond the scope of this investigation--best to contact the mfg. (Honestly I have no idea).

Comment: I am a novice at this: Can you check this piano : Studiologic NumaCompact 88-Key : It is apparently only  13.9 pounds, which seems to be the sweet deal of deals.

Comment: @Akiva. While the weight of the Studiologic NumaCompact 88-Key is appealing, it's difficult for me to determine if the USB port will also grant power. There is a 9v adapter. I recommend contacting the mfg or a retailer near you to sort out the power supply.

Answer (score -2):

The lightest Midi keyboard with full-size keys that I know of is the rollable midi keyboard at 6 lbs. But it only has 61 keys. Here's a video:

and here's a sales link:
[http://www.amazon.com/Electronic-Foldable-Padded-Keyboard-Rollable/dp/B005E6PH12](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005E6PH12)

There's an 88 key version but I have no idea of its playability:
[http://www.amazon.com/Jianxiu-Electronic-Piano-Keyboard-Flexible/dp/B00AOK3396](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AOK3396)
It also weighs 6 lbs.

Comment: Kevin - please do not copy and paste answers into multiple questions!

Comment: Refer to previous answers instead?

Comment: Sometimes using identical answers can be fine, but it usually indicates the questions should be dupes. In this instance, the two questions seem to be remarkably similar, so you can flag as a duplicate. That way the mods can merge them or close as dupe as needed.